# Grub not showing the boot menu

Tags: grub2

I have two hard drives. First with Ubuntu. Second, where I just installed ClearLinux. But GRUB doesn’t display the boot menu and immediately boots Ubuntu.

Some information:

```
➜  ~ lsblk -l | grep -v snap
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop29   7:29   0 310,8M  1 loop 
sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
sda1     8:1    0   149M  0 part 
sda2     8:2    0 232,8G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 111,8G  0 disk 
sdb1     8:17   0 111,8G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

```
➜  ~ sudo update-grub                                                                                                         
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Création du fichier de configuration GRUB…
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-89-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-89-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-88-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-88-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Clear Linux OS trouvé sur /dev/sda2
fait
```

and :

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

How to configure GRUB to display boot menu ? Other answers atlk about a `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT`. But it is not in grub config file.

Note : I see talking about EFI, but I don't know very about UEFI/EFI ...

**Edit** : By pressing Shift at computer boot, i can display the grub boot menu. But Grub list only display Ubuntu !

Thanks !

Comment: So add `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` if it is not there. and don't forget to update grub.

Comment: Hello @Pilot6 , according to documentation, this parameter is not relevant for me :(

Comment: In my 20.04 it is used. I didn't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is used for an older version of grub.

Change

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

to

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

and then run `update-grub`

This does the same thing that commenting out GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT in older versions of grub did.

Comment: It's working ! Thanks

Comment: Both ways work.

Comment: What do you mean by "older version of grub". I read the latest doc and `hidden` is still there.

Comment: The default config file has changed because newer better options are available.